# How do I load an web page into a div upon a user click on a link?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery and I'm looking to have a user click on a link and load the server response (in this case a one line confirmation) in the same div the link is in. I've gone round and round on this and can't seem to get it right. Here is the code I have from another post on this site which was similar but not close enough for me to grok...

```
<a href="http://10.0.1.2:8888/?ACT=24&tag_id=8" class="load_link">Add to Watchlist*</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {  
  $(function() {  
     $('.load_link').click(function() {  
        $(this).next('div').load(this.href);  
        return false;  
     });  
  });  
})(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the anchor is wrapped inside a div and you want to load the response in this div you could use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://10.0.1.2:8888/?ACT=24&tag_id=8" class="load_link">Add to Watchlist*</a>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$(this).closest('div').load(this.href);
```

if there is a div adjacent to the anchor:

```
<a href="http://10.0.1.2:8888/?ACT=24&tag_id=8" class="load_link">Add to Watchlist*
<div></div>
```

then the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the content into the containing div then the link gets replaced.
Hence add a span/div with in the main div that has the link and use this child span/div to load the content.

e.g:

```
<div>
    <span class="content"></span>
    <a href="http://10.0.1.2:8888/?ACT=24&tag_id=8" class="load_link">Add to Watchlist*</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {  
    $(function() {  
         $('.load_link').click(function() {  
                $(this).siblings(".content").load(this.href);  
                return false;  
         });  
    });  
})(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it wouldn't work for me. No errors, just didn't refresh the div but the call was passed to the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting point is to install Firebug and enter a debug session so that you can step through the code. Also you want to do the binding on document.ready() to ensure you bind after DOM is ready.

Comment: I'll check this out for the future. Thanks.